# Identification of a Fantasy book About Fairies that are like plants

Tags: story-identification, fairy

The Book I read about 4 years ago was about a girl who later in the book starts to grow a flower bud on her back. Turns out she's a fall fairy which is a higher class of fairy. The fairies are organized in a Season system. With Winter being like royalty and very rare, fall being upper class and rare, spring being middle class and summer being the lower class servants and most common. In the book the fairies are similar to plants. For example breathing in Carbon and breathing out Oxygen. As well as the guy fairies "pollinating" the girl fairies by putting their pollen covered hands into the center of the girl fairies blooms and they produce a seed which they plant, and a baby fairy is born.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [*Illusions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusions_(Pike_novel)) (or [*Wings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_(Pike_novel)) or [*Spells*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spells_(novel))) by Aprilynne Pike? The blooming happens in Book 1, but the pollenation thing is in Book 3.

Per wikipedia;

> Lauren ... is a fall fairy who was sent to live in the human world when she was young. In the first book, Wings, she finds out that she is a fall fairy when she first blossoms.

and

> When Tamani accompanies Yuki to a winter dance, his hands secrete pollen, which they only do when he is around a faerie in bloom.

[image]